# Endless loop when running Ionic cordova run android --livereload

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

I am unable to run the app in livereload mode.

command: ionic cordova  run android --livereload
error:    "[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm..." - stack in endless loop

Ionic info:

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.2 (C:\Users\Jasko\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.3\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 6.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 25 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 (update available: 0.8.0)
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (e:\Android\SDK)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Can you help ?

error log:

```
> ionic cordova run android --address 192.168.0.11  --device -l --ssl --debug

> npm.cmd run ionic:serve -- --address 192.168.0.11 --port 8101 --livereload-port 35730 --dev-logger-port 53704 --nobrowser --iscordovaserve --platform android --target cordova
[npm] > Real.Me@1.0.1 ionic:serve e:\Projects\xxx\src
[npm] > ionic serve -l --no-open "--address" "192.168.0.11" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--dev-logger-port" "53704" "--nobrowser" "--iscordovaserve" "--platform" "android" "--target" "cordova"
[npm] [WARN] The --nobrowser option has been deprecated. Please use --no-open.
[npm] > npm.cmd run ionic:serve -- --address 192.168.0.11 --port 8101 --livereload-port 35730 --dev-logger-port 53704 --nobrowser --platform android
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
[npm] [npm] > Real.Me@1.0.1 ionic:serve e:\Projects\xxx\src
[npm] [npm] > ionic serve -l --no-open "--address" "192.168.0.11" "--port" "8101" "--livereload-port" "35730" "--dev-logger-port" "53704" "--nobrowser" "--platform" "android"
[npm] [npm] [WARN] The --nobrowser option has been deprecated. Please use --no-open.
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
[npm] [npm] > npm.cmd run ionic:serve -- --address 192.168.0.11 --port 8101 --livereload-port 35730 --dev-logger-port 53704 --nobrowser --platform android
[npm] [INFO] Waiting for connectivity with npm...
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? [npm] Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Answer (score 0):

try to run:

```
ionic cordova run android -l
```

Without ***--l***

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue either with the project configuration or the global npm.

Try the same command in some other ionic applications.
If it works, you can be sure its a local issue with your project and not that with the npm.

Then try running the following commands,

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

just to re-fetch the platform data.

If the converse happens I suggest you to re install npm or move to a more stable version of node js.

Comment: yes it is definitely project config. when i create new projects it works fine. IS there any specific settings for this type of condig (see my Ionic info) that is required to run the app with -L option

Comment: Your ionic info seems to have no issue at my first look through it. But it much more seems like a platform issue. Can you confirm is it the same issue while you build for cordova browser? If it is so, i suggest you to move all of your files in the src folder to some newly created ionic project, replace the files. Also don't forget to re-install your missing npm packages. Try this and please do reply back.